# How to calculate tax on crypto currencies

Tags: capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency, israel

Suppose I buy some bitcoin for $100. Some time later, it is worth $200. I sell half of it for $100. Do I have to pay tax?

On one hand, "on paper" I gained $50, since the half that I sold was worth $50 when I bought it.

On the other hand, if tomorrow (or in 10 years) the bitcoin price goes to 0, my net gain will be 0.

How exactly should I compute the tax such that I do not end up paying tax for a net gain of 0?

Answer (score 2):

Your cost basis is $100; if you sell half of your holdings for $100, your cost basis on that is $50 and thus you had a $50 profit on which you owe taxes.

If, in the future your asset becomes worthless and you dispose of it for $0, you have a separate loss of $50 that you can deduct from your taxes at that time.

But for now, you don't get to use imaginary losses to avoid paying taxes on real profits.

Comment: "you have a separate loss of $50 that you can deduct from your taxes at that time." - but if at that time I do not have other profits on which I pay tax, what do I deduct this from?

Comment: Maybe, your regular income.  I don't know how it is in Israel, but in the US you can deduct up to $3000 per year in capital losses against regular income, and anything above that can be carried into future years.  It's probably similar in Israel - you can probably either deduct it from other income, or just hang on to the loss and deduct it in the future when you can.